# How to only show rows with columns that contain QStrings from a QStringList?

Tags: c++, qt, qstandarditemmodel, qsortfilterproxymodel

I've created a `SortFilterProxyModel` together with a `QStandardItemModel` and a `QTreeView`. I need to only show rows, where the second column is equal to one of the values in my `QStringList`. Can anyone tell me how to do this? I thought of `setFilterFixedString`, but this only works for a single `QString`, not for a List...

**My Code:**

```
#include "dicomtagsproxymodel.h"


DicomTagsProxyModel::DicomTagsProxyModel(QObject *parent) : QSortFilterProxyModel(parent)
{
}

DicomTagsProxyModel::~DicomTagsProxyModel(void)
{
}

bool DicomTagsProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow, const QModelIndex &sourceParent) const
{
    QModelIndex index1 = sourceModel()->index(sourceRow, 1, sourceParent);

    if (sourceModel()->data(index1).toString() == HOW TO GET THE VALUES OF MY STRINGLIST HERE?)
}
```

Comment: Override `filterAcceptsRow` and perform your filtering in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should subclass `QSortFilterProxyModel` then reimplement `protected` method `virtual bool filterAcceptsRow(int source_row, const QModelIndex & source_parent) const`. Inside reimplemented method you can check that value of index inside your `QStringList`.

Comment: I don't understand the last part: "Inside reimplemented method you can check that value of index inside your QStringList". How do I trigger this filtering, because the values in my stringlist change over time?

Comment: Then you should add to subclassed model some method for updating string list.